# R: Imputing NAs with random choice of female or male

Tags: r, dataframe, random, variable-assignment, imputation

I am working in R.

I have a data frame column with female or male and some NAs.

Now, I want to randomly assign female or male to the NA values in this column. I do not want to have all NAs be male or female but every NA randomly assigned either or.

How do I do that?

Best,
corkinabottle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to get an index of the `NA` elements in the column, then use `sample` with `size` specified as the number of NA elements to replace those NA with the `male` or `female` sampled

```
i1 <- is.na(df1$col1)
df1$col1[i1] <- sample(c('male', 'female'), size = sum(i1), replace = TRUE)
```

-output

```
df1
#    col1 col2
#1      a    1
#2 female    2
#3      b    3
#4   male    4
#5      a    5
#6      c    6
#7 female    7
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c('a', NA, 'b', NA, 'a', 'c', NA), col2 = 1:7)
```

Answer (score 2):

With `dplyr`, you can apply an `if_else` based on whether a column is `NA`, then randomly sample from m/f and replace.

Using @akrun's `df1`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(across(col1, ~if_else(is.na(.), sample(c("m", "f"), n(), replace = TRUE), .)))
```

Output

```r
  col1 col2
1    a    1
2    f    2
3    b    3
4    m    4
5    a    5
6    c    6
7    m    7
```

Comment: You don't need `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.  From `R 4.0`, it is by default